# Как сделать кроссдоменный запрос

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, запрос

Помогите кто нибудь пытаюсь делать кроссдоменный запрос:

```
<?
$post = array(
        'navigator'=>'all',
        'cat'=>'30',
        'spm'=>'a21bp.8294655.banner_cat.143.eUVtcW',
        'search_type'=>'0',
        '_input_charset'=>'utf-8',
        'json'=>'on',
        'nid'=>'',
        'abtest'=>'_AB-LR517-LR854-LR895-PR517-PR854-PR895',
        'type'=>'',
        'uniqpid'=>'',
        'uniqpid'=>'',
        '_ksTS'=>'1490278507514_27',
        'callback'=>'__jsonp_cb',
        '_ksTS'=>'1490278507514_27',
        'cna'=>'h7C4EE/xFgsCAV OV4tMTBCf',
    );
?> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "//world.taobao.com/search/json.htm?<?=http_build_query($post)?>",
        dataType: "text",
        jsonpCallback: '__jsonp_cb',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Но выводит ошибку:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed acces
```

Comment: это нормальное поведение. кроссдоменные запросы по умолчанию запрещены.

Comment: Как тогда разрешит, и делать дальше свой парсер?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы работал твой кроссдоменный запрос, нужно что бы в ответе сервера был соответствующий заголовок (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`) где вместо звездочки можно указать конкретный домен для которого разрешены ajax запросы, если его нет, забудь про ajax ;) это всё политика безопасности, можешь почитать чем это чревато [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain#cors)
+ у тебя в ajax должен быть указан `crossdomain:true;`

Answer (score 0):

Можно:

Есть небольшой трюк с PHP. И этот трюк будет работать не только с Google, но и с любыми сайтами, к которым у вас нет доступа и вы не можете добавить Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Нам нужно создать PHP-файл (например. getContentFromUrl.php) на нашем сервере и сделать обращение к нему.

**PHP**

```
<?php

$ext_url = $_POST['ext_url'];

echo file_get_contents($ext_url);

?>
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'getContentFromUrl.php', // link to your PHP file
    data: {
        // url куда наш сервер будет отправлять запрос, который мы не можем сделать через AJAX
        'ext_url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // теперь мы можем взять любые данные из внешнего url, потому что у нас есть вся страница
        var $h1 = $(data).find('h1').html();

        $('h1').text($h1);
    },
    error:function() {
        console.log('Error');
    }
});
```

**Как это работает:**

1. Ваш браузер с помощью JS отправит запрос на ваш сервер
2. Ваш сервер отправит запрос на любой другой сервер и получит ответ
3. Ваш сервер отправит этот ответ в ваш JS файл

И мы можем добавить event типа onClick на кнопку. Надеюсь, это поможет!